# salesforce page layout section - security

Tags: security, standard-objects, pagelayoutassignment

salesforce page layout section - security

I have added a section on page layout which renders my custom visualforce related list, it works fine for certain admin user, except for one sales profile, I checked object permission, visualforce, apex, field level access, all of them have read access to records.

I also added to the record type/page layout as well, but the sales user can't able to see it. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: does is show an error or it doesn't display at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page is displaying just the header of your "related list" then it might be that in the "sales profile" users don't have access to these records due to sharing restrictions. Does the VF-page have a Apex controller defined? If so, check if the class is defined with "with sharing" clause.

Comment: I tried with with sharing and without sharing as well, I don't see any impact

Comment: there is some confusion with pagelayout/record type assignment for different user, thats why id didn't show. I changed page layout assignments it works, thanks!